# EF6 Code First, Context fluent API: How to set same field properties for multiple entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have serveral entites inherited from the same base class

```
public class BaseEntity
{
   public string CreatedUser { get; set; }
   public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
   public string ChangedUser{ get; set; }
   public DateTime? ChangedDate { get; set; }

}
```

Now in my my context builder I do not want to assign these field properties in every builder method seperatly.

I want a generalized method where I could add to each entitiy builder method like

```
private static void BasisFields(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, Entity<TEntity> entitiy)
{
    modelBuilder.entitiy()
        .Property(k => k.CreatedUser)
        .HasMaxLength(32)
        .HasColumnType("varchar");

    modelBuilder.entitiy()
        .Property(k => k.CreatedDate)
        .HasColumnType("datetime");

    modelBuilder.entitiy()
        .Property(k => k.ChangedUser)
        .HasMaxLength(32)
        .HasColumnType("varchar");

    modelBuilder.entitiy()
        .Property(k => k.ChangedDate)
        .HasColumnType("datetime");

}
```

But this code above is not correct, because I am a C# beginner...

How does it should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the method generic:

```
private static void BasisFields<T>(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
        .Property(k => k.CreatedUser)
        .HasMaxLength(32)
        .HasColumnType("varchar");

    modelBuilder.Entitity<T>()
        .Property(k => k.CreatedDate)
        .HasColumnType("datetime");

    modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
        .Property(k => k.ChangedUser)
        .HasMaxLength(32)
        .HasColumnType("varchar");

    modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
        .Property(k => k.ChangedDate)
        .HasColumnType("datetime");    
}
```

The generic constraint `where T : BaseEntity` ensures you can call it only with types that inherit `BaseEntity` and gives you access to the `BaseEntity`  properties inside the method body.

Now you should call it for every entity which inherits `BaseEntity` like

```
BasisFields<DerivedEntityA>(modelBuilder);
BasisFields<DerivedEntityB>(modelBuilder);
...
```

If you want to make that process automatic for every entity which inherits `BaseEntity`, you can use the `DbModelBuilder.Types<T>` method:

> Begins configuration of a lightweight convention that applies to all entities and complex types in the model that inherit from or implement the type specified by the generic argument.

So instead of writing a method and calling it for every derived entity, you can simply use:

```
modelBuilder.Types<BaseEntity>().Configure(c =>
{
    c.Property(k => k.CreatedUser)
        .HasMaxLength(32)
        .HasColumnType("varchar");

    c.Property(k => k.CreatedDate)
        .HasColumnType("datetime");

    c.Property(k => k.ChangedUser)
        .HasMaxLength(32)
        .HasColumnType("varchar");

    c.Property(k => k.ChangedDate)
        .HasColumnType("datetime");    
});
```

Comment: Thats exactly I was looking for. Thank you.